How does Israel's "neither confirm nor deny" policy work?
Just a few examples:
Neither confirmed nor denied:

Haniyeh (Hamas leader) was  assassinated on 2024-07-31 in Iran (probably) by Israel. "Israel has neither confirmed nor denied involvement".

Lebanon pager attacks on 2024-09-17 and 2024-09-18 were (probably) carried out by Israel. "Israel has neither confirmed nor denied any role in the explosions".


Confirmed:

Nasrallah assassinated in Lebanon by Israel on 2024-09-27 (IDF)

Ibrahim Aqil assassinated in Lebanon by Israel on 2024-09-20 (IDF)


Which operations does Israel confirm? And which does it "neither confirm nor deny" (sometimes called the "Glomar response")?
My guess is that Mossad operations are usually "neither confirmed nor denied", while IDF operations are usually confirmed. But I am looking for actual explicit policy statements and/or academic descriptions about this (rather than just my mere guess).

Are you looking for logic in the politics of war?

There are plenty of instances of government mystery-speak.  Ukraine at some point was very coy about explosions in Russia.  "No comment" is another one that comes to mind and is not infrequently used in many countries.  When it comes to assassinations, since this is the tag used here, denial or veiled admissions are the norm, rather than the exception.  The use of this term does not seem to justify a question by itself.

Policy event happened, journalist asks senior government official at press conference: 'did you do that?' official responds: 'no comment'

They probably judge the public mood and use whatever they feel is more advantageous for them. For example, maybe the pager attack also had some civilian (non Hezbollah) casualties, so better not to brag too much about it.

I'm not gonna vote to close this, but I'd be really impressed if there's a policy manual/document for this [even for a given government], or even a discernible pattern.

@Barmar: Are you looking for logic in the politics of war? Yes that is precisely much of the work of political scientists, economists, historians, and other social scientists (who are the experts I hope will answer this question). (This may come as a surprise to you.)

It's very unlikely that for any given country there is a public protocol how to confirm or not confirm actions done by that country. For obvious reasons the existence of such a protocol would invalidate ... "we neither confirm nor deny"-statements as that would be a confirmation...
So just in general why one would use such a statement:

Mask the process. Like the glomar article mentions that the confirming the existence of an police investigation, reveals the existence of a police investigation and hence enables suspects to cover their trail.
Veiled admission in case of criminal activity. So if you commit a crime that acts as morally, legally and politically acts, which could trigger consequences. Whether that's invoking international law, crafting propaganda narratives or declaring war or respond with military operations. While doing the same on a "maybe" might look like an exaggeration that again could be actionable.
Fake admission: If everyone expects that to be "basically an admission of guilt", one can also use that to invoke the idea of admission for things one hasn't actually done. So if the police insinuates that they are investigating everything, they live rent free in the criminals heads and put pressure on them without actually expending any resources, maybe they don't even have these resources in the first place.
The mixture of fake admissions and veiled admissions creates paranoia in the opponent who might see a conspiracy behind every accident or an accident after real conspiracies. So unreasonably high security makes operations more costly and scarce while reduced security (because the enemy will be able to bypass them anyway) makes them more easy. Spreading the security makes them lower. Actual operations are more protected if every investigations focus on accidents, which conversely appear as if the opponent has superhuman capabilities of hiding their involvement. Suspicions of moles, rats and whatnot might make an enemy turn inwards if a source of an "attack" cannot be found aso

So there are plenty of reasons to do such things. Also Captain Obvious: Large scale military operations are so hard to hide that you might as well admit them as they are going to be unveiled within very short time anyway... While secret service operations are likely more ... secret.
Also just a speculation but Israel has ~10 million people, Lebanon ~5 million people and Iran ~80 million people. So as Israel probably has the best military in the region, a war with Lebanon would not be much of a problem, while a war with Iran would be a different thing. Now if Iran starts a war to wipe out Israel, Israel is likely going to get support by the international community, while if Israel openly attacks Iran with an initial strike and not a localized response and would thus triggers a war, then any doubt on helping Israel could be the end of that state. So probably both sides usually avoid open confrontation, but Iran allegedly finances terrorism while Israel allegedly has these "neither confirm nor deny"-situations. But again that is more of a speculating part.

Population size is a bit misleading. In a country like Iran, not all parts of the military age population (e.g. women) can be mobilized. In a country like Japan, much of the very large population is too old to mobilize. In a country like Israel, service is compulsory for men.

Not confirming also allows backers of the country to convince themselves that the country isn't committing crimes.

@uberhaxed Sure population size isn't everything but it already gives you a rough estimate of certain key facts, like idk total number of potential soldiers, militarization rates, total GDP aso. So even if Iran's GDP per capita is lower the total GDP is only 20% lower than Israels and while in Israel ~10% are already active or reserve in Iran it's just 1% so the potential to mobilize is much bigger in countries with more people.

@JohnDallman Would say that is somewhere in the veiled admission as well as the speculative parts, though whether that does or doesn't happen would be subject to speculation.

We also now know that Israel has near-total air supremacy over its own territory, and presumably extending beyond its borders by a few tens of miles. That means that any invading ground force from Iran could be targeted (and obliterated) without any possibility of response.

@Valorum The other side of the medal is that this air supremacy is kind of a necessity given that the most frequent angle of attack is rocketry or now drones strikes. So not sure how that works against ground troops and I'm not interested in speculating a war in the middle east, the situation seems to be bad enough as it is...

" For obvious reasons the existence of such a protocol would invalidate ... "we neither confirm nor deny"-statements as that would be a confirmation..." Huh? If Israel were to publicly say "We have a protocol of never confirming nor denying assassinations", and an assassination happens, the policy wouldn't be a confirmation or denial.

@Acccumulation The question doesn't ask for the existence of such a protocol but what is written in it. If you would know when they deny something it wouldn't be useful to deny it anymore. If there was such a document and if the public would know it, the government in question would change its tactics and we would know as much as before. Maybe, with lots of statistics we can find some correlations and can make some educated guesses.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution You seem to be just ignoring my point. haxor789 said there'd be no point to it, I explained how there is a point, and you simply said "no, there isn't a point" without addressing what I said. "The question doesn't ask for the existence of such a protocol but what is written in it." Yes. I said "If Israel were to publicly say "We have a protocol of never confirming nor denying assassinations"". That's an example of what is written in a protocol. How would Israel saying that they don't comment on assassinations make it not useful to not comment on assassinations?

@Acccumulation Fair enough it would on a technical level answer the question if they revealed a protocol saying "we don't comment on conspiracy theories of 'did you do it?'", because that protocol would just be a refusal to answer the question. What I and other's had in mind is more of a protocol that lets you decipher the level of involvement from the denial and such a protocol would be self-defeating as it would confirm or deny to those knowledgeable of the protocol, meaning it sure wouldn't be public.

@Acccumulation Also as the question said, assassinations are both being confirmed and "no commented" on, so that can't be the policy.

@Acccumulation: I think one problem with a blanket policy of never confirming nor denying assassinations is that it naively presumes that not commenting about an assassination made towards their own leaders is a good strategy; you'd probably want to deny those, but because of that policy, you can't, because otherwise you now reveal your hand when you don't comment on political opponents you do send an assassin after...
